# Retain SIDs and TNS when upgrading Oracle

Tags: oracle-11g

I am researching the process to upgrade Oracle from 11.2.0.1 to 11.2.0.3. I am planning on using the DBUA utility. My question is, will the DBUA make the necessary changes to retain my SIDs and update TNS so that no application changes will need to be made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will. The database SID will remain the same, and thus, no edits needed in the TNS files. The applications will be able to access/use the database as they used to, no client modification is needed.